# Weblogic domain is not getting created because of jrockit error

Tags: java-7, weblogic11g

I am creating a Basic Weblogic server domain(11g, version 10.3.5.0 ). And in the JDK selection Window, in Available JDKs , ' JRockit SDK 1.7.0_55 @ C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_55' is selected..

The domain gets created, now i check the 'Start Admin Server' checkbox and click 'Done' . The process of starting server runs in the cmd, but it halts with the following error::

starting weblogic with Java version:

Unrecognized option: -jrockit

Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.

Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.

My Jdk(64-bit) is installed correctly according to me, JAVA_HOME and those things are correct. jrockit comes bundled with JDK , so why this error, any leads will be very helpful..

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that WebLogic 10.3.5 only supports Suns Java JDK 1.6.0_24+ OR JRockit R28.1.3-1.6.0_24+.

It appears as though Weblogic 10.3.5 is not compatible with Java 7, try re-installing/configurring with a Java 6 version installed.

[Source: Oracle Installation Docs](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24902_01/doc.91/e18840/install_config_win.htm#EOHWL115)